# Compiling the Linux Kernel using g++

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to compile the Linux kernel (written in c) using g++. Is this possible? If not, could you suggest ways of accomplishing it?

Comment: So you want to compile C code with a C++ compiler? Why, if I may?

Comment: NO i just want to check the incompatabilities of c and c++.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do that??? Just use gcc. Compiling towards a C++ environment/runtime is not possible as in the kernel there is no way to run a C++ runtime. This would imply having exception handling available for example, which is very problematic in the kernel. So you have to stick to a C compiler like intel's C compiler `icc` or `gcc`.

Here is another question that might interest you:
[Is it possible to compile Linux kernel with something other than gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689327/is-it-possible-to-compile-linux-kernel-with-something-other-than-gcc)?

Another Reference:
[Why don't we rewrite the Linux kernel in C++?](http://www.tux.org/lkml/#s15-3)