# Why does this compile without errors? And why does it run on a 32-bit machine but not a 64?

Tags: c, gcc

I am able to compile this with gcc using the `-Wextra -g` flags and I get no errors. Why does the compiler not catch that I don't return anything from a non-void function? Also, I've run this on a 32-bit and a 64-bit machine. It ran perfectly fine on the 32-bit, and even printed 'Apple stem length 10. Apple color r'. But it seg faults on the 64-bit machine. What is gcc doing here that gives me such unpredictable behavior and why is it not giving me any errors at compile time?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct apple
{
    int stem_length;
    char color;
};

struct apple* alloc_apple(const int stem_length, const char color)
{
    struct apple* new_apple = (struct apple*)malloc(sizeof(struct apple));
    new_apple->stem_length = stem_length;
    new_apple->color = color;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct apple* some_apple = alloc_apple(10, 'r');
    printf("Apple stem length %d. Apple color %c\n", some_apple->stem_length,
        some_apple->color);

    free(some_apple);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-Wextra` should be not the first option. Use `-Wall` to enable almost all warnings (you may add `-ansi -pedantic`); and `-Wextra` will enable several more warnings.

Comment: unless you also add `-Werror`, no warnings will be treated as errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alloc_apple` fails to `return new_apple;` at the end.  This may work by coincidence if `new_apple` happens to be left lying around in the register the return value is expected in when the function returns (on i386 this is usually `EAX`), but allowing control to reach the end of a non-`void` returning function produces undefined behavior (which may include anything from accidentally working as expected to [causing demons to fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

I am fairly certain that if you compile with `gcc -Wall` (enable all warnings) it would point out the issue; `return-type` is the specific warning.

The function wouldn't even work for compilers that use the ancient convention of returning the value of the last expression evaluated if no `return` is present, since the last expression evaluates to the value of `color`.

Comment: I understand that, why does gcc not catch this though?

Comment: @clementine Because C doesn't require it to. You should always use the `-Wall` flag though, to enable warnings.

Comment: @nos Also, if I read the manual correctly, `-Wextra` does not imply `-Wall`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `-Wextra`, but this is wrong option.

Gcc (and most unix compilers) uses `-Wall` option to enable most warnings, including the one you want to see, the `-Wreturn-type`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

> `-Wall`
>
> This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. 
>   -Wall turns on the following warning flags:
>
> ... list of `-Wreturn-type` and 30 more `-W...` flags

And your `-Wextra` only enables several additional warnings which are not turned on by `-Wall`.

> `-Wextra`
>
> This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall.
>   ... list of 12 rare `-W...` options

Example:

```
$ gcc t.c -Wextra
# No output
$ gcc t.c -Wall
t.c: In function ‘alloc_apple’:
t.c:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

So, just use "`-Wall`" to get most warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` to get more. And sometimes you can also use set `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic -pedantic-errors` to be sure that your program is very close to C99 standard (but system headers have non-standard code and this is not caught).

Also use `clang`, it has better warnings and better warnings set by default:

```
$ clang t.c
t.c:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors? What errors?

"Not returning anything from a non-void function" has never been considered a formal "error" (i.e. a constraint violation) in C. (BTW, it is not an "error" in C++ either). It is just how the language is defined. Some compilers might issue a warning, but in general case they are not allowed to treat this as a constraint violation.

As a side note, the difference between C and C++ in that regard is that in C++ forgetting to return something is always *undefined behavior*. In C the behavior is undefined only if you attempt to *use* the function's result in the calling code. Otherwise, if the returned value is ignored by the caller, C sees it as perfectly normal legal code.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're failing to return a value from a function.

This is undefined behavior.  It just "seems to work" on 32-bit, and it crashes on 64-bit.  If you're curious *why* it's failing, the first step is to get a stack trace.

As to "why didn't GCC tell me?"

It can:

> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html
>
> *-Wreturn-type*
>
> Warn whenever a function is defined with a return-type that defaults to int. Also warn about any return statement with no
>   return-value in a function whose return-type is not void.
>
> For C++, a function without return type always produces a diagnostic message, even when *-Wno-return-type* is specified. The only
>   exceptions are main and functions defined in system headers.

Personally, I almost always use these switches during development:

`gcc -g -pedantic -Wall ...`

Comment: And I want also recommend little-known `-pedantic-errors` and switch to clang. Docs says that `-pedantic-errors` just turn all pedantic warnings into errors; but actually it [also disables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14629651/196561) several gcc-specific non-standard extensions like VLAIS.